# replace all occurence of a string with a character using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I wan to replace all occurrence of a string with single quote but with `str.replace` it only replaces the first occurrence of the script:

`"7<singleQuote>1 inche<singleQuote>s"`

Code

```
var data = "7<singleQuote>1 inche<singleQuote>s"
var output = data.replace("<singleQuote>","'")
```

Output: `7'1 inche<singleQuote>s`

I want to replace `<singleQuote>` with `'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex with `g` flag:

```
var output = data.replace(/<singleQuote>/g, "'");
```

**MDN:** [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Example%3a_Defining_the_regular_expression_in_replace).